# Adding a left border to a table cell when hovered

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a border to the left of the text in such a way that when I hover the row, the border of the first cell gets highlighted and the user knows which row they're in.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eq70r3zb/) of what I have so far:

```css
#table {
  border: 1px solid#e9e9e9;
}
tr:hover {
  background-color: #e9e9e9;
}
tr:hover > td:first-child {
  border-left: 2px solid #1B8645;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Address</th>
    </tr>

 <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>8742</td>
            <td>5476235street</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>8742</td>
            <td>5476235street</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>8742</td>
            <td>5476235street</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>8742</td>
            <td>5476235street</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>Active</td>
            <td>8742</td>
            <td>5476235street</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

However, as seen in the fiddle, when I hover the row, the text is pushed a bit and makes the hover look messy and distorted. I'm trying to set a line in such a way that when hovered, the text shouldn't be pushed away and the table content shouldn't move.

Here is how the border is applied on hover:

```
tr:hover >  td:first-child {
    border-left: 2px solid #1B8645;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you should add a transparent color line for no hover status

```
tr>td:first-child{
    border-left: 2px solid transparent;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/serGlazkov/eq70r3zb/1/

Comment: By far the simplest non-hacky solution.

Comment: Also, use `border-spacing: 0` on `table` so that there are no gaps between cells on hover. Use padding on `td` to create some space inside the cells. Also, place the heading row inside `thead` so that you can target only `tbody` rows on hover. [Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/wmpsqq5q/)

Answer (score 0):

The border is going to push the text to the right as it should. Have you tried making the text shift to the left with a negative margin (margin-left: -2px) when the hover occurs if possible? Or adding a bit of padding (2px) in this case when not on hover and taking it away on hover.